# An airplane holds a straight southerly course with a speed of $250$ km / h

Tags: trigonometry

An airplane holds a straight southerly course with a speed of $250$ km / h relative to the air. It flies through the air stream, which moves due east at a speed of $50$ km / h

a) In what direction relative to said ground moves the plane?

b) What speed does the plane have relative to the ground?

Answer for: 
a) I did not understand the first question (answer is $168.7$ degrees South, $11.3$ degrees East)

Answer for:
b) I used Pythagoras' Theorem but I got $2750$ km / h.
The answer in the book is $255$ km/ h

Help if you can.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to understand this is to draw a triangle.

The plane is moving 250 south: Therefore your first arrow show be of length 250 and pointing downwards.

Secondly, the wind is due east 50: Therefore at the end of the you should draw an arrow across which has length 50.

Next step: Connect the beginning of your first line [250] with the end of your second line, forming a triangle.

Now you can label your triangle: $\theta$ will be the angle between the 250 line and the longest line (hypontonuese).

From here you can use Trigonometry (For me I learnt using SOH COH TOA - if you do as well in this case it is TOA.) I.e $\theta=tan(\frac{50}{250})^{-1}$

You are doing (b) correctly just check your calculations

Comment: Not everyone learns trigonometric functions with SOH COH TOA.  So perhaps just say: by trigonometry, $\tan \theta = 50/250$, and continue from there.

Comment: I made a slight change. Think that should be enough to help her through the probelm